# Parsing rules - how to make them play nice together

Tags: parsing, token, rules

So I'm doing a Parser, where I favor flexibility over speed, and I want it to be easy to write grammars for, e.g. no tricky workaround rules (fake rules to solve conflicts etc, like you have to do in yacc/bison etc.)

There's a hand-coded Lexer with a fixed set of tokens (e.g. PLUS, DECIMAL, STRING_LIT, NAME, and so on) right now there are three types of rules:

- TokenRule: matches a particular token
- SequenceRule: matches an ordered list of rules
- GroupRule: matches any rule from a list

For example, let's say we have the TokenRule 'varAccess', which matches token NAME (roughly /[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*/), and the SequenceRule 'assignment', which matches [expression, TokenRule(PLUS), expression].

Expression is a GroupRule matching either 'assignment' or 'varAccess' (the actual ruleset I'm testing with is a bit more complete, but that'll do for the example)

But now let's say I want to parse

```
var1 = var2
```

And let's say the Parser begins with rule Expression (the order in which they are defined shouldn't matter - priorities will be solved later). And let's say the GroupRule expression will first try 'assignment'. Then since 'expression' is the first rule to be matched in 'assignment', it will try to parse an expression again, and so on until the stack is filled up and the computer - as expected - simply gives up in a sparkly segfault.

So what I did is - SequenceRules add themselves as 'leafs' to their first rule, and become non-roôt rules. Root rules are rules that the parser will first try. When one of those is applied and matches, it tries to subapply each of its leafs, one by one, until one matches. Then it tries the leafs of the matching leaf, and so on, until nothing matches anymore.

So that it can parse expressions like

```
var1 = var2 = var3 = var4
```

Just right =) Now the interesting stuff. This code:

```
var1 = (var2 + var3)
```

Won't parse. What happens is, var1 get parsed (varAccess), assign is sub-applied, it looks for an expression, tries 'parenthesis', begins, looks for an expression after the '(', finds var2, and then chokes on the '+' because it was expecting a ')'.

Why doesn't it match the 'var2 + var3' ? (and yes, there's an 'add' SequenceRule, before you ask). Because 'add' isn't a root rule (to avoid infinite recursion with the parse-expresssion-beginning-with-expression-etc.) and that leafs aren't tested in SequenceRules otherwise it would parse things like

```
reader readLine() println()
```

as

```
reader (readLine() println())
```

(e.g. '1 = 3' is the expression expected by add, the leaf of varAccess a)

whereas we'd like it to be left-associative, e.g. parsing as

```
(reader readLine()) println()
```

So anyway, now we've got this problem that we should be able to parse expression such as '1 + 2' within SequenceRules. What to do? Add a special case that when SequenceRules begin with a TokenRule, then the GroupRules it contains are tested for leafs? Would that even make sense outside that particular example? Or should one be able to specify in each element of a SequenceRule if it should be tested for leafs or not? Tell me what you think (other than throw away the whole system - that'll probably happen in a few months anyway)

P.S: Please, pretty please, don't answer something like "go read this 400pages book or you don't even deserve our time" If you feel the need to - just refrain yourself and go bash on reddit. Okay? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LL(k) parsers (top down recursive, whether automated or written by hand) require refactoring of your grammar to avoid left recursion, and often require special specifications of lookahead (e.g. ANTLR) to be able to handle k-token lookahead.  Since grammars are complex, you get to discover k by experimenting, which is exactly the thing you wish to avoid.

YACC/LALR(1) grammars aviod the problem of left recursion, which is a big step forward.  The bad news is that there are no real programming langauges (other than Wirth's original PASCAL) that are LALR(1).  Therefore you get to hack your grammar to change it from LR(k) to LALR(1), again forcing you to suffer the experiments that expose the strange cases, and hacking the grammar reduction logic to try to handle K-lookaheads when the parser generators (YACC, BISON, ... you name it) produce 1-lookahead parsers.

GLR parsers (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLR_parser) allow you to avoid almost all of this nonsense. If you can write a context free parser, under most practical circumstances, a GLR parser will parse it without further effort.  That's an enormous relief when you try to write arbitrary grammars.   And a really good GLR parser will directly produce a tree.

BISON has been enhanced to do GLR parsing, sort of. You still have to write complicated logic to produce your desired AST, and you have to worry about how to handle failed parsers and cleaning up/deleting their corresponding (failed) trees.   The [DMS Software Reengineering Tookit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) provides standard GLR parsers for any context free grammar, and automatically builds ASTs without any additional effort on your part; ambiguous trees are automatically constructed and can be cleaned up by post-parsing semantic analyis. We've used this to do define 30+ language grammars including C, including C++  (which is widely thought to be hard to parse [and it is almost impossible to parse with YACC] but is straightforward with real GLR); see [C+++ front end parser and AST builder](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CppFrontEnd.html) based on DMS.

Bottom line: if you want to write grammar rules in a straightforward way, and get a parser to process them, use GLR parsing technology.   Bison *almost* works.  DMs *really* works.

Answer (score 0):

My favourite parsing technique is to create recursive-descent (RD) parser from a PEG grammar specification. They are usually very fast, simple, and flexible. One nice advantage is you don't have to worry about separate tokenization passes, and worrying about squeezing the grammar into some LALR form is non-existent. Some PEG libraries are listed [here][1].

Sorry, I know this falls into throw away the system, but you are barely out of the gate with your problem and switching to a PEG RD parser, would just eliminate your headaches now.